# Parsing JSON in Java without knowing JSON format

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I am trying to parse JSON strings in Java and find the key-value pairs so that I can determine the approximate structure of the JSON object since object structure of JSON string is unknown.

For example, one execution may have a JSON string like this:

```
  {"id" : 12345, "days" : [ "Monday", "Wednesday" ], "person" : { "firstName" : "David", "lastName" : "Menoyo" } }
```

And another like this:

```
  {"url" : "http://someurl.com", "method" : "POST", "isauth" : false }
```

How would I cycle through the various JSON elements and determine the keys and their values? I looked at `jackson-core`'s [`JsonParser`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html). I see how I can grab the next "token" and determine what type of token it is (i.e., field name, value, array start, etc), but, I don't know how to grab the actual token's value.

For example:

```
public void parse(String json)  {
  try {
     JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
     JsonParser parser = f.createParser(json);
     JsonToken token = parser.nextToken();
     while (token != null) {
        if (token.equals(JsonToken.START_ARRAY)) {
           logger.debug("Start Array : " + token.toString());
        } else if (token.equals(JsonToken.END_ARRAY)) {
           logger.debug("End Array : " + token.toString());
        } else if (token.equals(JsonToken.START_OBJECT)) {
           logger.debug("Start Object : " + token.toString());
        } else if (token.equals(JsonToken.END_OBJECT)) {
           logger.debug("End Object : " + token.toString());
        } else if (token.equals(JsonToken.FIELD_NAME)) {
           logger.debug("Field Name : " + token.toString());
        } else if (token.equals(JsonToken.VALUE_FALSE)) {
           logger.debug("Value False : " + token.toString());
        } else if (token.equals(JsonToken.VALUE_NULL)) {
           logger.debug("Value Null : " + token.toString());
        } else if (token.equals(JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT)) {
           logger.debug("Value Number Float : " + token.toString());
        } else if (token.equals(JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT)) {
          logger.debug("Value Number Int : " + token.toString());
        } else if (token.equals(JsonToken.VALUE_STRING)) {
           logger.debug("Value String : " + token.toString());
        } else if (token.equals(JsonToken.VALUE_TRUE)) {
           logger.debug("Value True : " + token.toString());
        } else {
           logger.debug("Something else : " + token.toString());
        }
        token = parser.nextToken();
     }
  } catch (Exception e) {
     logger.error("", e);
  }
}
```

Is there a class in `jackson` or some other library (`gson` or `simple-json`) that produces a tree, or allows one to cycle through the json elements and obtain the actual key names in addition to the values?

Comment: Well, the simple part is parsing into maps and lists -- something that every reasonable JSON parser can do just fine.  The harder part, of course, is figuring out what the data means, if it's totally different each time.

Comment: (If you've not done so yet, visit json.org and understand the basic JSON syntax.  All values are either numbers, Booleans, strings, objects (maps), arrays, or "null" -- nothing more complex.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and link. I'm actually quite familiar with JSON; just not parsing without annotations and/or immediate transition into an existing pojo structure.

Comment: In the rest of the world, outside of Java, that's how you do it.  Parse, get back a generic object, if necessary do `instanceOf` or whatever to see what you got, then work from there.  You never have a totally unknown format, but sometimes the format can vary based on certain factors.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Take a look at  [Jacksons built-in tree model feature](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel).

And your code will be:

```
public void parse(String json)  {
       JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();

       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
       JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(json);  

       Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = rootNode.fields();
       while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {

           Map.Entry<String,JsonNode> field = fieldsIterator.next();
           System.out.println("Key: " + field.getKey() + "\tValue:" + field.getValue());
       }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. Thank you. For anyone else who reads this, I found that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13926850/2333544) may help too.

Comment: In any other language this would simply be known as "parsed JSON", and would be what you regularly worked with.

Comment: Try catch is required around the #readTree call since ti throws checked JsonProcessingException

Comment: missing a + in "Key:"field.getKey() :)

Answer (score 24):

If a different library is fine for you, you could try [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java):

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(myJSONString);
String[] keys = JSONObject.getNames(object);

for (String key : keys)
{
    Object value = object.get(key);
    // Determine type of value and do something with it...
}
```

Comment: Good to know as I am not confined to the jackson library. Thank you.

Comment: object.getName() is not a member of '_value getNames is not a member of 
  org.json.JSONObject_'

Comment: @AshishRatan you're right. `getNames()` is a static method of JSONObject. I fixed the code.

Comment: How would this work if you don't know the number of levels of nesting? Don't you need to use recursion?

Comment: @user3282164 Yes, in that case you need recursion. That's the part of `// Determine type of value and do something with it...` ;-)

Comment: org.json library has problems it's not working if there was json array in string.

Answer (score 7):

Find the following code for Unknown Json Object parsing using Gson library.

```
public class JsonParsing {
static JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

public static HashMap<String, Object> createHashMapFromJsonString(String json) {

    JsonObject object = (JsonObject) parser.parse(json);
    Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> set = object.entrySet();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> iterator = set.iterator();
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry = iterator.next();
        String key = entry.getKey();
        JsonElement value = entry.getValue();

        if (null != value) {
            if (!value.isJsonPrimitive()) {
                if (value.isJsonObject()) {

                    map.put(key, createHashMapFromJsonString(value.toString()));
                } else if (value.isJsonArray() && value.toString().contains(":")) {

                    List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    JsonArray array = value.getAsJsonArray();
                    if (null != array) {
                        for (JsonElement element : array) {
                            list.add(createHashMapFromJsonString(element.toString()));
                        }
                        map.put(key, list);
                    }
                } else if (value.isJsonArray() && !value.toString().contains(":")) {
                    map.put(key, value.getAsJsonArray());
                }
            } else {
                map.put(key, value.getAsString());
            }
        }
    }
    return map;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**[JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) of unknown format to [HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110252/what-are-the-differences-between-hashmap-vs-hashtable-in-theory/31243387#31243387)**

*writing [JSON](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1) And reading [Json](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson)*

```
public static JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
public static void main(String args[]) {
     writeJson("JsonFile.json");
     readgson("JsonFile.json");
}
public static void readgson(String file) {
    try {
        System.out.println( "Reading JSON file from Java program" );

        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader( file );
        com.google.gson.JsonObject object = (JsonObject) parser.parse( fileReader );

        Set <java.util.Map.Entry<String, com.google.gson.JsonElement>> keys = object.entrySet();
        if ( keys.isEmpty() ) {
            System.out.println( "Empty JSON Object" );
        }else {
            Map<String, Object> map = json_UnKnown_Format( keys );
            System.out.println("Json 2 Map : "+map);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Input File Does not Exists.");
    }
}
public static Map<String, Object> json_UnKnown_Format( Set <java.util.Map.Entry<String, com.google.gson.JsonElement>> keys ){
    Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for (Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : keys) {
        String keyEntry = entry.getKey();
        System.out.println(keyEntry + " : ");
        JsonElement valuesEntry =  entry.getValue();
        if (valuesEntry.isJsonNull()) {
            System.out.println(valuesEntry);
            jsonMap.put(keyEntry, valuesEntry);
        }else if (valuesEntry.isJsonPrimitive()) {
            System.out.println("P - "+valuesEntry);
            jsonMap.put(keyEntry, valuesEntry);
        }else if (valuesEntry.isJsonArray()) {
            JsonArray array = valuesEntry.getAsJsonArray();
            List<Object> array2List = new ArrayList<Object>();
            for (JsonElement jsonElements : array) {
                System.out.println("A - "+jsonElements);
                array2List.add(jsonElements);
            }
            jsonMap.put(keyEntry, array2List);
        }else if (valuesEntry.isJsonObject()) {             
             com.google.gson.JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) parser.parse(valuesEntry.toString());                    
             Set <java.util.Map.Entry<String, com.google.gson.JsonElement>> obj_key = obj.entrySet();
             jsonMap.put(keyEntry, json_UnKnown_Format(obj_key));
        }
    }
    return jsonMap;
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void writeJson( String file ) {

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    json.put("Key1", "Value");
    json.put("Key2", 777); // Converts to "777"
    json.put("Key3", null);
    json.put("Key4", false);

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.put("Array-Value1");
        jsonArray.put(10); 
        jsonArray.put("Array-Value2");

    json.put("Array : ", jsonArray); // "Array":["Array-Value1", 10,"Array-Value2"]

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put("Obj-Key1", 20);
        jsonObj.put("Obj-Key2", "Value2");
        jsonObj.put(4, "Value2"); // Converts to "4"

    json.put("InnerObject", jsonObj);

        JSONObject jsonObjArray = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray objArray = new JSONArray();
            objArray.put("Obj-Array1");
            objArray.put(0, "Obj-Array3");
        jsonObjArray.put("ObjectArray", objArray);

    json.put("InnerObjectArray", jsonObjArray);

        Map<String, Integer> sortedTree = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        sortedTree.put("Sorted1", 10);
        sortedTree.put("Sorted2", 103);
        sortedTree.put("Sorted3", 14);

    json.put("TreeMap", sortedTree);        

    try {
        System.out.println("Writting JSON into file ...");
        System.out.println(json);
        FileWriter jsonFileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        jsonFileWriter.write(json.toJSONString());
        jsonFileWriter.flush();
        jsonFileWriter.close();
        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample I wrote shows how I parse a json and mess every number inside it:

```
public class JsonParser {

    public static Object parseAndMess(Object object) throws IOException {
        String json = JsonUtil.toJson(object);
        JsonNode jsonNode = parseAndMess(json);
        if(null != jsonNode)
            return JsonUtil.toObject(jsonNode, object.getClass());

        return null;
    }

    public static JsonNode parseAndMess(String json) throws IOException {
        JsonNode rootNode = parse(json);
        return mess(rootNode, new Random());
    }

    private static JsonNode parse(String json) throws IOException {
        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
        JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(json);
        return rootNode;

    }

    private static JsonNode mess(JsonNode rootNode, Random rand) throws IOException {
        if (rootNode instanceof ObjectNode) {
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = rootNode.fields();
            while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = fieldsIterator.next();
                replaceObjectNode((ObjectNode) rootNode, field, rand);
            }
        } else if (rootNode instanceof ArrayNode) {
            ArrayNode arrayNode = ((ArrayNode) rootNode);
            replaceArrayNode(arrayNode, rand);
        }
        return rootNode;
    }

    private static void replaceObjectNode(ObjectNode rootNode, Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field, Random rand)
            throws IOException {
        JsonNode childNode = field.getValue();
        if (childNode instanceof IntNode) {
            (rootNode).put(field.getKey(), rand.nextInt(1000));
        } else if (childNode instanceof LongNode) {
            (rootNode).put(field.getKey(), rand.nextInt(1000000));
        } else if (childNode instanceof FloatNode) {
            (rootNode).put(field.getKey(), format(rand.nextFloat()));
        } else if (childNode instanceof DoubleNode) {
            (rootNode).put(field.getKey(), format(rand.nextFloat()));
        } else {
            mess(childNode, rand);
        }
    }

    private static void replaceArrayNode(ArrayNode arrayNode, Random rand) throws IOException {
        int arrayLength = arrayNode.size();
        if(arrayLength == 0)
            return;
        if (arrayNode.get(0) instanceof IntNode) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                arrayNode.set(i, new IntNode(rand.nextInt(10000)));
            }
        } else if (arrayNode.get(0) instanceof LongNode) {
            arrayNode.removeAll();
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                arrayNode.add(rand.nextInt(1000000));
            }
        } else if (arrayNode.get(0) instanceof FloatNode) {
            arrayNode.removeAll();
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                arrayNode.add(format(rand.nextFloat()));
            }
        } else if (arrayNode.get(0) instanceof DoubleNode) {
            arrayNode.removeAll();
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                arrayNode.add(format(rand.nextFloat()));
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                mess(arrayNode.get(i), rand);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void print(JsonNode rootNode) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(rootNode.toString());
    }

    private static double format(float a) {
        return Math.round(a * 10000.0) / 100.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you be satisfied with a `Map` from Jackson?

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> map = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>(){});
```

Or maybe a `JsonNode`?

```
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(String jsonString)
```