# Convert a JSON String to a HashMap

Tags: java, json, dictionary

I'm using Java, and I have a String which is JSON:

```
{
"name" : "abc" ,
"email id " : ["abc@gmail.com","def@gmail.com","ghi@gmail.com"]
}
```

Then my Map in Java:

```
Map<String, Object> retMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

I want to store all the data from the JSONObject in that HashMap.

Can anyone provide code for this?  I want to use the `org.json` library.

Comment: I don't know why json.org JSONObject does not have a getter for the private map member variable...

Comment: **Solution in Kotlin please check this** using gson
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53763826/8052227

Comment: But why is question asking about `JSONObject` when that seems to be superfluous type that is not needed at all? Reading JSON as `Map` is simple using any number of good Java JSON Libraries like Jackson, GSON, Genson, Moshi. So why does OP "want" to use org.json?

Comment: @staxMan, Due to the organization policy, sometimes you are bound to use the inbuilt libraries only. Hence, I had to use the org.json only.

Comment: @VikasGupta ok that makes sense, if running on such platform (Android probably)

Answer (score 255, accepted):

In recursive way:

```
public static Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
    Map<String, Object> retMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    
    if(json != JSONObject.NULL) {
        retMap = toMap(json);
    }
    return retMap;
}

public static Map<String, Object> toMap(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    Iterator<String> keysItr = object.keys();
    while(keysItr.hasNext()) {
        String key = keysItr.next();
        Object value = object.get(key);
        
        if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
            value = toList((JSONArray) value);
        }
        
        else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
            value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
        }
        map.put(key, value);
    }
    return map;
}

public static List<Object> toList(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        Object value = array.get(i);
        if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
            value = toList((JSONArray) value);
        }

        else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
            value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
        }
        list.add(value);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Using Jackson library:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

Map<String, Object> mapping = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonStr, HashMap.class);
```

Comment: You can safely catch those exceptions and throw runtime exceptions or assertions instead. You have already checked that the key exists and that the array has a value at the index that you check. Also, no sense in creating the retMap before checking for null as it is created twice when json != null. Looks good though.

Comment: what imports / external lib does this use? Eclipse can't dissolve JSONArray and JSONObject

Comment: @Gewure , use org.json.

Comment: There is a compile time error when Jackson Library is used as it is in the code.   It can be fixed like below :       TypeReference<HashMap<Integer, Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<Integer, Object>>() {
    };
    Map<Integer, Object> mapping = new ObjectMapper().readValue("", typeRef);

Answer (score 183):

Using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), you can do the following:

```
Map<String, Object> retMap = new Gson().fromJson(
    jsonString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType()
);
```

Comment: But i dont want to use GSon library. I am allowed to use only "org.json" lirary'.

Comment: how to read it into the `jsonString`? whats the difference between `jsonString` and json object?

Comment: @Toon can you do it other way around ?

Comment: @SharpEdge. Do you mean like this: `new Gson().toJson(map);` ?

Comment: Does this only serialize into primitive objects? How about if there is a Date I want serialized into the Map as well?

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe you can tell GSon how to serialize a date: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873020/gson-date-format

Comment: Instead of using "new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType()" I prefer to use the "TypeToken.getParameterized" method. So to get the type of the mentioned HashMap you would do this: TypeToken.getParameterized(HashMap.class, String.class, Object.class). Here's my example in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61930940/8070550

Comment: When using the Gson to convert string to hashmap<String, Object>, the integers are getting converted to Floats and this is creating a huge problem when using the converted Hashmap. If I use hashmap<String, Integer>, it works perfectly. But this is not my case. I have to use hashmap<String, Object>.

Comment: For `Map<String, Integer>` Its converting to `Double`. this is what I am using `Map<String, Integer> typeMap = Maps.newHashMap(); new Gson().fromJson(jsonData, typeMap.getClass());`

Answer (score 67):

Hope this will work, try this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
Map<String, Object> response = new ObjectMapper().readValue(str, HashMap.class);
```

str, your JSON String

As Simple as this, if you want emailid,

```
String emailIds = response.get("email id").toString();
```

Comment: Chose this solution. Also handy, when your JSON string is meant to have complex data types like lists, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: as I was using jackson library in my application beforehand, so this is the best answer to my problem. Thanks :)

Comment: With this solution I am getting error - com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{

Answer (score 17):

I just used Gson

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new Gson().fromJson(json.toString(), HashMap.class);
```

Comment: Now this is what I wanted.

Comment: In Kotlin, this looks like this: 
`val map = Gson().fromJson(json.toString(), HashMap<String, Object>().javaClass)`

Answer (score 9):

Here is Vikas's code ported to JSR 353:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonException;
import javax.json.JsonObject;

public class JsonUtils {
    public static Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(JsonObject json) {
        Map<String, Object> retMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if(json != JsonObject.NULL) {
            retMap = toMap(json);
        }
        return retMap;
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> toMap(JsonObject object) throws JsonException {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Iterator<String> keysItr = object.keySet().iterator();
        while(keysItr.hasNext()) {
            String key = keysItr.next();
            Object value = object.get(key);

            if(value instanceof JsonArray) {
                value = toList((JsonArray) value);
            }

            else if(value instanceof JsonObject) {
                value = toMap((JsonObject) value);
            }
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static List<Object> toList(JsonArray array) {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            Object value = array.get(i);
            if(value instanceof JsonArray) {
                value = toList((JsonArray) value);
            }

            else if(value instanceof JsonObject) {
                value = toMap((JsonObject) value);
            }
            list.add(value);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is giving me errors in distinguishing between JsonObject and JSONObject.

Comment: @sirvon Can you clarify?  The JSR 353 code doesn't have a "JSONObject".   I don't recommend that you mix JSON technologies.  Pick one or the other.

Comment: Note that the resulting Map still contains wrappers (e.g. JsonString instead of a plain String). I have posted an alternative solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65634179/388827

Answer (score 8):

Latest Update: I have used `FasterXML Jackson Databind`<sup>[2.12.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.12.3)</sup> to Convert JSON string to Map, Map to JSON string.

```java
// javax.ws.rs.core.Response clientresponse = null; // Read JSON with Jersey 2.0 (JAX-RS 2.0)
// String json_string = clientresponse.readEntity(String.class);
String json_string = "[\r\n"
        + "{\"domain\":\"stackoverflow.com\", \"userId\":5081877, \"userName\":\"Yash\"},\r\n"
        + "{\"domain\":\"stackoverflow.com\", \"userId\":6575754, \"userName\":\"Yash\"}\r\n"
        + "]";
System.out.println("Input/Response JSON string:"+json_string);
ObjectMapper mapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
//java.util.Map<String, String> map = mapper.readValue(json_string, java.util.Map.class);
List<Map<String, Object>> listOfMaps = mapper.readValue(json_string, new com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference< List<Map<String, Object>>>() {});

System.out.println("fasterxml JSON string to List of Map:"+listOfMaps);

String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(listOfMaps);
System.out.println("fasterxml List of Map to JSON string:[compact-print]"+json);

json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(listOfMaps);
System.out.println("fasterxml List of Map to JSON string:[pretty-print]"+json);
```

output:

```
Input/Response JSON string:[
{"domain":"stackoverflow.com", "userId":5081877, "userName":"Yash"},
{"domain":"stackoverflow.com", "userId":6575754, "userName":"Yash"}
]
fasterxml JSON string to List of Map:[{domain=stackoverflow.com, userId=5081877, userName=Yash}, {domain=stackoverflow.com, userId=6575754, userName=Yash}]
fasterxml List of Map to JSON string:[compact-print][{"domain":"stackoverflow.com","userId":5081877,"userName":"Yash"},{"domain":"stackoverflow.com","userId":6575754,"userName":"Yash"}]
fasterxml List of Map to JSON string:[pretty-print][ {
  "domain" : "stackoverflow.com",
  "userId" : 5081877,
  "userName" : "Yash"
}, {
  "domain" : "stackoverflow.com",
  "userId" : 6575754,
  "userName" : "Yash"
} ]
```

---

**Converting a JSON String to Map**

```java
public static java.util.Map<String, Object> jsonString2Map( String jsonString ) throws org.json.JSONException {
    Map<String, Object> keys = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
    
    org.json.JSONObject jsonObject = new org.json.JSONObject( jsonString ); // HashMap
    java.util.Iterator<?> keyset = jsonObject.keys(); // HM
    
    while (keyset.hasNext()) {
        String key =  (String) keyset.next();
        Object value = jsonObject.get(key);
        System.out.print("\n Key : "+key);
        if ( value instanceof org.json.JSONObject ) {
            System.out.println("Incomin value is of JSONObject : ");
            keys.put( key, jsonString2Map( value.toString() ));
        } else if ( value instanceof org.json.JSONArray) {
            org.json.JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(key);
            //JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(value.toString());
            keys.put( key, jsonArray2List( jsonArray ));
        } else {
            keyNode( value);
            keys.put( key, value );
        }
    }
    return keys;
}
```

**Converting JSON Array to List**

```java
public static java.util.List<Object> jsonArray2List( org.json.JSONArray arrayOFKeys ) throws org.json.JSONException {
    System.out.println("Incoming value is of JSONArray : =========");
    java.util.List<Object> array2List = new java.util.ArrayList<Object>();
    for ( int i = 0; i < arrayOFKeys.length(); i++ )  {
        if ( arrayOFKeys.opt(i) instanceof org.json.JSONObject ) {
            Map<String, Object> subObj2Map = jsonString2Map(arrayOFKeys.opt(i).toString());
            array2List.add(subObj2Map);
        } else if ( arrayOFKeys.opt(i) instanceof org.json.JSONArray ) {
            java.util.List<Object> subarray2List = jsonArray2List((org.json.JSONArray) arrayOFKeys.opt(i));
            array2List.add(subarray2List);
        } else {
            keyNode( arrayOFKeys.opt(i) );
            array2List.add( arrayOFKeys.opt(i) );
        }
    }
    return array2List;
}
public static Object keyNode(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof String || o instanceof Character) return (String) o;
    else if (o instanceof Number) return (Number) o;
    else return o;
}
```

**Display JSON of Any Format**

```java
public static void displayJSONMAP( Map<String, Object> allKeys ) throws Exception{
    Set<String> keyset = allKeys.keySet(); // HM$keyset
    if (! keyset.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator<String> keys = keyset.iterator(); // HM$keysIterator
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            Object value = allKeys.get( key );
            if ( value instanceof Map ) {
                System.out.println("\n Object Key : "+key);
                    displayJSONMAP(jsonString2Map(value.toString()));
            }else if ( value instanceof List ) {
                System.out.println("\n Array Key : "+key);
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(value.toString());
                jsonArray2List(jsonArray);
            }else {
                System.out.println("key : "+key+" value : "+value);
            }
        }
    }    
    
}
```

[Google.gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760138/parsing-json-in-java-without-knowing-json-format/31984993#31984993) to HashMap.

Answer (score 7):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;


public class JsonUtils {

    public static Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(JSONObject json) {
        Map<String, Object> retMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if(json != null) {
            retMap = toMap(json);
        }
        return retMap;
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> toMap(JSONObject object) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Iterator<String> keysItr = object.keySet().iterator();
        while(keysItr.hasNext()) {
            String key = keysItr.next();
            Object value = object.get(key);

            if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
                value = toList((JSONArray) value);
            }

            else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
                value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
            }
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static List<Object> toList(JSONArray array) {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            Object value = array.get(i);
            if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
                value = toList((JSONArray) value);
            }

            else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
                value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
            }
            list.add(value);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some explanation: how does your answer improve on other existing answers to this question

Answer (score 7):

try this code :

```
 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                try
                {

                   Iterator<?> keys = jsonObject.keys();

                    while (keys.hasNext())
                    {
                        String key = (String) keys.next();
                        String value = jsonObject.getString(key);
                        params.put(key, value);

                    }


                }
                catch (Exception xx)
                {
                    xx.toString();
                }
```

Comment: Convert string to object: `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);`

Answer (score 6):

Convert using Jackson :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject().put("abc", "pqr").put("xyz", 5);

Map<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(obj.toString(), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can convert any `JSON` to `map` by using **Jackson** library as below:

```
String json = "{\r\n\"name\" : \"abc\" ,\r\n\"email id \" : [\"abc@gmail.com\",\"def@gmail.com\",\"ghi@gmail.com\"]\r\n}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
// convert JSON string to Map
map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
System.out.println(map);
```

Maven Dependencies for **Jackson** :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Hope this will help. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Jackson API as well for this :

```
    final String json = "....your json...";
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final MapType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(
        Map.class, String.class, Object.class);
    final Map<String, Object> data = mapper.readValue(json, type);
```

Answer (score 3):

There’s an older answer using `javax.json` posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27679348/388827), however it only converts `JsonArray` and `JsonObject`, but there are still `JsonString`, `JsonNumber`, and `JsonValue` wrapper classes in the output. If you want to get rid of these, here’s my solution which will unwrap everything.

Beside that, it makes use of Java 8 streams and is contained in a single method.

```
/**
 * Convert a JsonValue into a “plain” Java structure (using Map and List).
 * 
 * @param value The JsonValue, not <code>null</code>.
 * @return Map, List, String, Number, Boolean, or <code>null</code>.
 */
public static Object toObject(JsonValue value) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(value, "value was null");
    switch (value.getValueType()) {
    case ARRAY:
        return ((JsonArray) value)
                .stream()
                .map(JsonUtils::toObject)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    case OBJECT:
        return ((JsonObject) value)
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Entry::getKey,
                        e -> toObject(e.getValue())));
    case STRING:
        return ((JsonString) value).getString();
    case NUMBER:
        return ((JsonNumber) value).numberValue();
    case TRUE:
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    case FALSE:
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    case NULL:
        return null;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected type: " + value.getValueType());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you hate recursion - using a Stack and javax.json to convert a Json String into a List of Maps:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Stack;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.stream.JsonParser;

public class TestCreateObjFromJson {
    public static List<Map<String,Object>> extract(InputStream is) {
        List extracted = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(is);

        String nextKey = "";
        Object nextval = "";
        Stack s = new Stack<>();
        while(parser.hasNext()) {
            JsonParser.Event event = parser.next();
            switch(event) {
                case START_ARRAY :  List nextList = new ArrayList<>();
                                    if(!s.empty()) {
                                        // If this is not the root object, add it to tbe parent object
                                        setValue(s,nextKey,nextList);
                                    }
                                    s.push(nextList);
                                    break;
                case START_OBJECT : Map<String,Object> nextMap = new HashMap<>();
                                    if(!s.empty()) {
                                        // If this is not the root object, add it to tbe parent object
                                        setValue(s,nextKey,nextMap);
                                    }
                                    s.push(nextMap);
                                    break;
                case KEY_NAME : nextKey = parser.getString();
                                break;
                case VALUE_STRING : setValue(s,nextKey,parser.getString());
                                    break;
                case VALUE_NUMBER : setValue(s,nextKey,parser.getLong());
                                    break;
                case VALUE_TRUE :   setValue(s,nextKey,true);
                                    break;
                case VALUE_FALSE :  setValue(s,nextKey,false);
                                    break;
                case VALUE_NULL :   setValue(s,nextKey,"");
                                    break;
                case END_OBJECT :   
                case END_ARRAY  :   if(s.size() > 1) {
                                        // If this is not a root object, move up
                                        s.pop(); 
                                    } else {
                                        // If this is a root object, add ir ro rhw final 
                                        extracted.add(s.pop()); 
                                    }
                default         :   break;
            }
        }

        return extracted;
    }

    private static void setValue(Stack s, String nextKey, Object v) {
        if(Map.class.isAssignableFrom(s.peek().getClass()) ) ((Map)s.peek()).put(nextKey, v);
        else ((List)s.peek()).add(v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use google gson library to convert json object.

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/‎

Other librarys like Jackson are also available.

This won't convert it to a map. But you can do all things which you want.

Comment: Without using any wrapper library is also very easy to convert.

Answer (score 1):

Brief and Useful:

```
/**
 * @param jsonThing can be a <code>JsonObject</code>, a <code>JsonArray</code>,
 *                     a <code>Boolean</code>, a <code>Number</code>,
 *                     a <code>null</code> or a <code>JSONObject.NULL</code>.
 * @return <i>Appropriate Java Object</i>, that may be a <code>Map</code>, a <code>List</code>,
 * a <code>Boolean</code>, a <code>Number</code> or a <code>null</code>.
 */
public static Object jsonThingToAppropriateJavaObject(Object jsonThing) throws JSONException {
    if (jsonThing instanceof JSONArray) {
        final ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

        final JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonThing;
        final int l = jsonArray.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) list.add(jsonThingToAppropriateJavaObject(jsonArray.get(i)));
        return list;
    }

    if (jsonThing instanceof JSONObject) {
        final HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        final Iterator<String> keysItr = ((JSONObject) jsonThing).keys();
        while (keysItr.hasNext()) {
            final String key = keysItr.next();
            map.put(key, jsonThingToAppropriateJavaObject(((JSONObject) jsonThing).get(key)));
        }
        return map;
    }

    if (JSONObject.NULL.equals(jsonThing)) return null;

    return jsonThing;
}
```

---

Thank [@Vikas Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24012023/5318303).

Answer (score 0):

The following parser reads a file, parses it into a generic `JsonElement`, using Google's `JsonParser.parse` method, and then converts all the items in the generated JSON into a native Java `List<object>` or `Map<String, Object>`.

***Note***: The code below is based off of [Vikas Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2915208/vikas-gupta)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24012023/1762224).

## GsonParser.java

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;

public class GsonParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            print(loadJsonArray("data_array.json", true));
            print(loadJsonObject("data_object.json", true));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void print(Object object) {
        System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(object).toString());
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> loadJsonObject(String filename, boolean isResource)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException, JsonIOException, JsonSyntaxException, MalformedURLException {
        return jsonToMap(loadJson(filename, isResource).getAsJsonObject());
    }

    public static List<Object> loadJsonArray(String filename, boolean isResource)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException, JsonIOException, JsonSyntaxException, MalformedURLException {
        return jsonToList(loadJson(filename, isResource).getAsJsonArray());
    }

    private static JsonElement loadJson(String filename, boolean isResource) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException, JsonIOException, JsonSyntaxException, MalformedURLException {
        return new JsonParser().parse(new InputStreamReader(FileLoader.openInputStream(filename, isResource), "UTF-8"));
    }

    public static Object parse(JsonElement json) {
        if (json.isJsonObject()) {
            return jsonToMap((JsonObject) json);
        } else if (json.isJsonArray()) {
            return jsonToList((JsonArray) json);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(JsonObject jsonObject) {
        if (jsonObject.isJsonNull()) {
            return new HashMap<String, Object>();
        }

        return toMap(jsonObject);
    }

    public static List<Object> jsonToList(JsonArray jsonArray) {
        if (jsonArray.isJsonNull()) {
            return new ArrayList<Object>();
        }

        return toList(jsonArray);
    }

    private static final Map<String, Object> toMap(JsonObject object) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        for (Entry<String, JsonElement> pair : object.entrySet()) {
            map.put(pair.getKey(), toValue(pair.getValue()));
        }

        return map;
    }

    private static final List<Object> toList(JsonArray array) {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

        for (JsonElement element : array) {
            list.add(toValue(element));
        }

        return list;
    }

    private static final Object toPrimitive(JsonPrimitive value) {
        if (value.isBoolean()) {
            return value.getAsBoolean();
        } else if (value.isString()) {
            return value.getAsString();
        } else if (value.isNumber()){
            return value.getAsNumber();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static final Object toValue(JsonElement value) {
        if (value.isJsonNull()) {
            return null;
        } else if (value.isJsonArray()) {
            return toList((JsonArray) value);
        } else if (value.isJsonObject()) {
            return toMap((JsonObject) value);
        } else if (value.isJsonPrimitive()) {
            return toPrimitive((JsonPrimitive) value);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

## FileLoader.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileLoader {
    public static Reader openReader(String filename, boolean isResource) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException {
        return openReader(filename, isResource, "UTF-8");
    }

    public static Reader openReader(String filename, boolean isResource, String charset) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException {
        return new InputStreamReader(openInputStream(filename, isResource), charset);
    }

    public static InputStream openInputStream(String filename, boolean isResource) throws FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException {
        if (isResource) {
            return FileLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
        }

        return new FileInputStream(load(filename, isResource));
    }

    public static String read(String path, boolean isResource) throws IOException {
        return read(path, isResource, "UTF-8");
    }

    public static String read(String path, boolean isResource, String charset) throws IOException {
        return read(pathToUrl(path, isResource), charset);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    protected static String read(URL url, String charset) throws IOException {
        return new Scanner(url.openStream(), charset).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    }

    protected static File load(String path, boolean isResource) throws MalformedURLException {
        return load(pathToUrl(path, isResource));
    }

    protected static File load(URL url) {
        try {
            return new File(url.toURI());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            return new File(url.getPath());
        }
    }

    private static final URL pathToUrl(String path, boolean isResource) throws MalformedURLException {
        if (isResource) {
            return FileLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path);
        }

        return new URL("file:/" + path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want no-lib version, here is the solution with regex:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> jsonStringToMap(String inputJsonString) {
    final String regex = "(?:\\\"|\\')(?<key>[\\w\\d]+)(?:\\\"|\\')(?:\\:\\s*)(?:\\\"|\\')?(?<value>[\\w\\s-]*)(?:\\\"|\\')?";
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputJsonString);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            map.put(matcher.group("key"), matcher.group("value"));
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using a switch expression.

```
static Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(Reader reader) {
  var jsonReader = Json.createReader(reader);
  var jsonValue = jsonReader.readValue(); // Removes duplicate keys (last one wins)
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  var map = (Map<String, Object>) jsonValueToObject(jsonValue);
  return map;
}

private static Object jsonValueToObject(JsonValue value) {
  return switch (value.getValueType()) {
    case OBJECT -> ((JsonObject) value).entrySet().parallelStream().collect(
        HashMap::new,
        (map, entry) -> map.put(entry.getKey(), jsonValueToObject(entry.getValue())),
        (map1, map2) -> map2.entrySet().forEach(entry -> map1.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())));
    case ARRAY -> ((JsonArray) value).stream().map(Utils::jsonValueToObject).collect(toList());
    case STRING -> ((JsonString) value).getString();
    case NUMBER -> ((JsonNumber) value).numberValue();
    case TRUE -> Boolean.TRUE;
    case FALSE -> Boolean.FALSE;
    default -> null; // Only JsonValue.NULL remains
  };
}
```

I didn't use the `Collectors.toMap()` collector, because it doesn't allow `null` values.

Answer (score -1):

Imagine u have a list of email like below. not constrained to any programming language,

```
emailsList = ["abc@gmail.com","def@gmail.com","ghi@gmail.com"]
```

Now following is JAVA code - for converting json to map

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject().put("name","abc").put("email id",emailsList);
Map<String, Object> s = jsonObj.getMap();
```

Comment: Which version of Java(6/7/8/9)? Which Edition(SE/EE/Other)? Which package does `JSONObject` of your code belongs to?

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question and maybe still relate to someone.
Let's say you have string HashMap `hash` and JsonObject `jsonObject`.

1) Define key-list.
Example:

```
ArrayList<String> keyArrayList = new ArrayList<>();  
keyArrayList.add("key0");   
keyArrayList.add("key1");
```

2) Create foreach loop, add `hash` from `jsonObject` with:

```
for(String key : keyArrayList){  
    hash.put(key, jsonObject.getString(key));
}
```

That's my approach, hope it answer the question.

Answer (score -3):

Using [json-simple](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1/json-simple-1.1.1.jar) you can convert data JSON to Map and Map to JSON.

```
try
{
    JSONObject obj11 = new JSONObject();
    obj11.put(1, "Kishan");
    obj11.put(2, "Radhesh");
    obj11.put(3, "Sonal");
    obj11.put(4, "Madhu");

    Map map = new  HashMap();

    obj11.toJSONString();

    map = obj11;

    System.out.println(map.get(1));


    JSONObject obj12 = new JSONObject();

    obj12 = (JSONObject) map;

    System.out.println(obj12.get(1));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.err.println("EROR : 01 :"+e);
}
```