# how to merge 2 json? java, Android

Tags: java, android

I want these:

> JSONObject json1 = {
>       "one": "1",
>      "two": "2",
>      "three": "3"
>   }
>   JSONObject json2 = {
>           "four": "4",
>           "five": "5",
>           "six": "6"
>       }

to Merge like this:

> JSONObject result = {
>           "one": "1",
>           "two": "2",
>           "three": "3",
>           "four": "4",
>           "five": "5",
>           "six": "6"
>       }

the method putALL doesn't work, getNames doesn't work either.

Comment: save both into an array and join into one array.

Comment: not a duplicate, I searched before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manually

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("first json");
 JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject("second json");
 Iterator<String> keys = obj2.keys();
 while( keys.hasNext() ) {
     String key =  keys.next();
     obj.put(key, obj2.optString(key);
 }
```

**edit**

or if your `JSONObject` contains different types of values you can use [opt(String key)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#opt(java.lang.String)) which returns a generic `Object`. Thanks to @Selvin for pointing that out

check for typo

Comment: of course it will work only for strings properties ...

Comment: it works with your example, that gives the point.

Comment: Interesting ... json.org API has no method to check the property type ... so it is not possible to make it more generic ... on the other hand ... removing last `}` from the first json and first `{` from second and concate those string with coma inside should do the thing ....

Comment: json has still the [get(key)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#get(java.lang.String)) which returns a generic object, that *should* cover more or less all the cases @Selvin. The string solution would definitely work, but I am not a fun of it (my personal taste)

Comment: uh, forgot about this method(or opt(key) ) ... so `obj.put(key, obj2.opt(key))` should do the thing for other types

Comment: thank you, you are great

Comment: @manuel_k, you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

for complex types: use java types:

1 convert to a map (not so easy)

[Convert a JSON String to a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720759/convert-a-json-string-to-a-hashmap)

2 append the maps

3 convert the map to json (easy)

new JSONObject(map);