# Saving JSON object to Firebase in Android

Tags: android, json, firebase, pojo

I am new to firebase, and I am trying to put JSON object data into my Firebase.
I know how to put data as a class object into Firebase, but I want to put JSON object data.

Is there any way to put JSON object data into Firebase without converting it as a POJO?

Comment: i think without POJO it is very difficult to store data into firebase .....

Comment: Firebase saves data as a json, but why can't I save data as json?

Comment: Can you please post a json data you want to store in firebase?

Comment: @shj see my answer you can save what ever json data you want in firebase using import json option in firebase

Comment: Java has no native format to represent JSON. In what format do you have the JSON data? If it's a `Map<String,Object>` then you can just pass that into `ref.setValue()` the same as a POJO (as Emin answered).

Comment: I think this is the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270153/pushing-json-file-to-firebase-database-android/39540908#39540908), I used its answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've tagged android in your question, so I guess you want to put some data in your firebase database from the Android client.

You've some JSON data and you want it to store in firebase database right? This is the step by step procedure to get it done.

I don't really know why are you trying to avoid POJO. It makes the total operation more simplified. Now let us assume you've a JSON string. You need to map your JSON to a java class to put it directly in the firebase. Firebase stores the data in a JSON-like format which is easily understandable.

I use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to map a JSON string to a specific java object. Its the easiest method I've found so far needs few lines of coding.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourPOJO myPOJO = gson.fromJson(jsonString, YourPOJO.class);
```

Now you've mapped your JSON string to `myPOJO` object successfully. You're ready to put this object in your Firebase database now.

Lets take the reference to your Firebase database and then call `setValue` in that specific node where you want put the data.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase(YOUR_FIREBASE_REF);
ref.setValue(myPOJO);
```

Simple!

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can achieve this. Start by converting your json to a string then do the following:

```
  String jsonString; //set to json string
  Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType());
```

I am using the "updateChildren" method because I want the JSON object added directly to the root of my child object

```
  firebaseDatabaseRef.child("users").child(uid).updateChildren(jsonMap);
```

If you don't care or you would like to set a new node, use

```
 firebaseDatabaseRef.child("users").child(uid).child({your new node}).setValue(jsonMap);
```

Comment: Just noticed another poster had the same method, I will leave my answer up bcos of the additional info on how to set the JSON object in the Firebase DB.

Answer (score 6):

It is so simple to also save **JSON value** on firebase. Let's say you have called your firebase reference

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/android/saving-data/fireblog");
```

Then you will pass your data with `Map` objects. `Map` keeps values with keys. In your case you will have a `String` key and `JSONObject` value.

```
Firebase userRef = ref.child("user");
Map<String, JSONObject> userMap= new HashMap<String, JSONObject>();
JSONObject tempObject = new JSONObject();

try{
   tempObject.put("birthday","1992");
   tempObject.put("fullName","Emin AYAR");
}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
userMap.put("myUser", tempObject);

userRef .setValue(userMap);
```

Comment: is it add value in Firebase database having key name myUser ?

Answer (score 5):

As suggested here: [Convert a JSON String to a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720759/convert-a-json-string-to-a-hashmap)

you can easily convert your json object/string to a `Map<String, Object>` (you don't even need to create a POJO):

```java
Firebase ref = new Firebase(YOUR_FIREBASE_REF);
Map<String, Object> map = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType());
ref.setValue(map);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution In Kotlin** because Auto Conversion convert it with compile time error saying :
["Not enough information to infer parameter T" with Kotlin and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267041/not-enough-information-to-infer-parameter-t-with-kotlin-and-android/45297610][1])

```
val jsonMap = Gson().fromJson<Any>(stringJson, object : TypeToken<HashMap<String, Any>>() {}.type)
```