# Pushing JSON file to Firebase database Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm experimenting with Google's new Firebase database service; and I was just wondering if it would be possible to push an entire JSON(Object?) to my database.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: In what format do you have the JSON object?

Comment: I don't actually have one yet, I'm just wondering if that would be the best way to go about it or if it would be possible to upload a raw .json file or something

Comment: If I have a JSON file, I usually upload it through the Firebase CLI `firebase database:set`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#database_commands. It can also be done through code, but I find the CLI easier for the cases I need it.

Comment: You can refer this example https://androidheight.blogspot.in/2017/04/firebase-reatime-database.html

Answer (score 0):

I parsed my JSONObject to a map using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720759/convert-a-json-string-to-a-hashmap) and then saved to firebase using setValue().