# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object would be serialized to `null`: Android

Tags: java, android, meteor

I have recently been setting up mobile apps to work with my meteor server. As a part of this I have to pass the meteor web app data from android. Unfortunately I have been receiving a error that tells me that the java object I am passing "would be serialized to `null`". How do I prevent this?

```
     JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            try{
                json.put("Foo", "1");
                json.put("Blah", 0);
            }catch (JSONException e){

            }
            Object[] object = new Object[1];
            object[0] = json;
            System.out.println(object + ", " + object[0] + ", " + object[0].toString());
            mMeteor.call("xxx", object, new ResultListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String result) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onError(String error, String reason, String details) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String error, String reason, String details) {

        }
    });
```

Android/Meteor interface Library function

```
 public void callWithSeed(final String methodName, final String randomSeed, final Object[] params, final ResultListener listener) {
    // create a new unique ID for this request
    final String callId = uniqueID();

    // save a reference to the listener to be executed later
    if (listener != null) {
        mListeners.put(callId, listener);
    }

    // send the request
    final Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put(Protocol.Field.MESSAGE, Protocol.Message.METHOD);
    data.put(Protocol.Field.METHOD, methodName);
    data.put(Protocol.Field.ID, callId);
    if (params != null) {
        data.put(Protocol.Field.PARAMS, params);
    }
    if (randomSeed != null) {
        data.put(Protocol.Field.RANDOM_SEED, randomSeed);
    }
    send(data);
}
```

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue, my first error was passing a `CharSequence` instead a `String` as a parameter (your `Object[]`), and my other error was passing an `Object[]` as another parameter (I solved this by sending a `String` instead, like : `String.valueOf(your_object_list)`) Dont forget to handle this on your server side, you will receive a `String` instead of an `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `JSONArray` to `List` & `JSONObject` to `HashMap` and then pass those instead of the raw `JSONObject` or `JSONArray`.

You can write a recursive function for the conversion in case of nested `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` or can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library for the conversion.

For more details about the conversion, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720759/convert-a-json-string-to-a-hashmap) may be helpful.