# How to convert Map created from JSON to another Map in Java?

Tags: java, json, hashmap, type-conversion

I got JSON file like this:

```
{
"issues": [
        {
           "no1": 5509,
           "date": 1451520000
        },
        {
           "no1": 6713,
           "date": 1451433600
        }],
"no2": [
    220380,
    163950,
    213330,
    215250,
    174300]
}
```

I need to create a map *issues* where the no1 value will be key of the map and date value will be a value of the map. I've got already method which transfers JSON to map from file, and I know how to get the *issues* which will be: `mapFromJson.get("issues");` what I get is:

```
issues=[{ no1: 5509.0, date: 1.45152E9}, {no1: 6713.0, date: 1.4514336E9}]
```

How to convert this to map?

Comment: "I've got already method which transfers JSON to map" - then what is the question?

Comment: Becouse this convert from file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to JSON using [JSON Library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107) (you must to attach JAR file in your project). Also, I found a good answer for convert JSON to Map in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720759/convert-a-json-string-to-a-hashmap). I recommended to use these functions.

Example:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(<your_json_string>);
ArrayList issues =  (ArrayList) jsonToMap(json).get("issues");
```

Each element in the `ArrayList issues`, it's already `HashMap`. For example, if you want to get `date` of `no1`, you could access of this way:

```
((HashMap)issues.get(0)).get("date")
```