# how can get data dynamically and parse any specific key and value without knowing name?

Tags: android, json

I am working on an module in which i have to get the json data and get array name (which is table name of android database) and all keys and value of array(which is keys=columns & values=data of columns) and array name(table name) and their related data can be more than 1 or in 20s or more . i do not know how to implement it because i have not done this kind of code before..please help me to solve this problem.

my json code is like.. every array name would be different this is an example only but data will coming like this

```
    {
    "MSG": "OK",
    "data": [
        {
            "strPrimaryKey": "iDeviceAppId",
            "Device_App": [
                {
                    "strAppName": "NI Data Dashbard",
                    "isDeleted": "0",
                    "strVersion": "2.3.0",
                    "dtCreateDate": "2018-04-09",
                    "iDeviceAppId": "0",
                    "dtUpdateDate": "2018-04-13",
                    "iOnHomeScreen": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: your json  is invalid json  check on this https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: i have edited my question now you can check.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the JSON you received into a map and then traverse the map to get what you need.

Comment: thank you for helping me..can you please help me with some code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720759/convert-a-json-string-to-a-hashmap check this question and have a try

Comment: It would be nice of you to vote up if my answer helped you