# How to parse the given string to map of string of map of string of object?

Tags: java, jackson

Hi my input string look like this

```
{
   6138249={
              value=[multi2, multi3, multi4], 
              key=TestMulticat
           }, 
   6161782={
              value=Traps (Bamboo / Box), 
              key=Observation gear
           }
}
```

I want to map this input string in `Map<String,Map<String,Object>>` in java.

As the input look more mysterious to me, i am not able to figure out the way to do the same.
I tried  `ObjectMapper` class from `jackson` but still not able to map. The code i write look like this

```
Map<String,Map<String,Object>> data=objectMapper.readValue(singledoc, Map.class);
```

Can somebody suggest me either approach to do this or solution, both will be equally helpful.

Comment: So `value` can be either a string or an array of strings? That's impolite of the implementer.

Comment: @chrylis yes i know thats impolite. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24012023/9223839) can be of help here, it is not jackson but  I still think it can be helpful. Basically you read your data as a Map<String, Object> and then you iterate though all values in the map and use instances to see if it is an array or a simple string.

Answer (score 0):

Your input doesn't look like valid json, as it has unquoted string values.
Json would look like this:

```
{
6138249:{
          value:["multi2", "multi3", "multi4"], 
          key:"TestMulticat"
       }, 
6161782:{
          value="Traps (Bamboo / Box)", 
          key="Observation gear"
       }
}
```

For such input you can use jackson:

```
objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> result = objectMapper
       .readValue(test, new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>() {});
```

`ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES` will help you to deal with unquoted field names, however there is no such option for unqouted values.

In your case as its not a json, you can either fix your serialization to produce valid jackson or write your own `Deserializer` for jackson handling this, because currently its not possible to read json with unquoted string values.