# Split the Multiple Array json string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, jsonparser

I have a JSON string of multiple arrays obtained from the front end of my application.

```
String editList = [{"gradingId":"9","lowerLimit":"34","upperLimit":"55"},{"gradingId":"11","lowerLimit":"23","upperLimit":"45"},{"gradingId":"37","lowerLimit":"20","upperLimit":"35"}]
```

i obtain individual elements as,

```
gradingId= 9
lowerLimit=34 
UpperLimit=55
```

and so on.

is there a way that I can access the gradingId, LowerLimit and upperLimit by there names?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24012023/6446770 this might help

Comment: what have you tried so far

Comment: Iterate through your array and then access the said key using either dot notation or bracket notation.

Comment: Could you show an example please?

Answer (score 1):

This will help you loop through the data

```js
let editList = [{"gradingId":"9","lowerLimit":"34","upperLimit":"55"},{"gradingId":"11","lowerLimit":"23","upperLimit":"45"},{"gradingId":"37","lowerLimit":"20","upperLimit":"35"}]

editList.map(listItem => {
  Object.keys(listItem).map(objItem => {
    console.log(objItem +'=' + listItem[objItem])
  })
})
```

Or if the keys are predefined. You can avoid the second loop and make use of the below code.

```js
let editList = [{"gradingId":"9","lowerLimit":"34","upperLimit":"55"},{"gradingId":"11","lowerLimit":"23","upperLimit":"45"},{"gradingId":"37","lowerLimit":"20","upperLimit":"35"}]

editList.map(listItem => {
  console.log("gradingId" +'=' + listItem["gradingId"])
  console.log("lowerLimit" +'=' + listItem["lowerLimit"])
  console.log("upperLimit" +'=' + listItem["upperLimit"])
})
```

Comment: I want to do this in java. Not in javascript

Comment: @KasunChathuranga then post the appropriate tags for your question. As of this moment you have [javascript] tag and no [java] tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
let editList = [
{"gradingId":"9","lowerLimit":"34","upperLimit":"55"},
{"gradingId":"11","lowerLimit":"23","upperLimit":"45"},
{"gradingId":"37","lowerLimit":"20","upperLimit":"35"}]

editList.forEach((list,index) => {
   console.log(editList[index]);
)
```

you could use forEach function for array in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate through `editList` as an array with a `for` loop, Array method, etc.
2. Assign a variable to an Object property using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

> ```
> editList[i][key]
> ```

```js
var editList = [{"gradingId": "9","lowerLimit": "34","upperLimit": "55"}, {"gradingId": "11","lowerLimit": "23","upperLimit": "45"}, {"gradingId": "37","lowerLimit": "20","upperLimit": "35"}];

function propVal(arr, key) {
  var res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    res.push(arr[i][key]);
  }
  return `${key}: ${res}`;
}

console.log(propVal(editList, "gradingId"));
console.log(propVal(editList, "lowerLimit"));
console.log(propVal(editList, "upperLimit"));
```