# Comparing JSON with arrays

Tags: java, json

I am trying to compare 2 JSON files, they have arrays with duplicated values.

My first JSON Object has an array like this:

```
"categories": [
            "May",
            "Apr",
            "Mar"
          ]
```

My second JSON object has an array like this:

```
"categories": [
            "May",
            "May",
            "Apr",
            "Apr",
            "Mar",
            "Mar"
          ]
```

I am comparing the JSON using flat maps that can be found in this link [comparing JSONs using guava](https://cassiomolin.com/2018/07/23/comparing-json-documents-in-java/)

Here is part of my code:

```
 private String smartJSONsCompare(JSONObject leftJson, JSONObject rightJson) {

    String result = "</br>";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
    Map<String, Object> leftMap = gson.fromJson(leftJson.toString(), type);
    Map<String, Object> rightMap = gson.fromJson(rightJson.toString(), type);
    Map<String, Object> leftFlatMap = FlatMapUtil.flatten(leftMap);
    Map<String, Object> rightFlatMap = FlatMapUtil.flatten(rightMap);
    MapDifference<String, Object> difference = Maps.difference(leftFlatMap, rightFlatMap);
    StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder("</br>");
    SB.append("Entries only on LEFT: </br>");
    difference.entriesOnlyOnLeft().forEach((key, value) -> SB.append(key + ": " + value + "</br>"));
    SB.append("Entries only on RIGHT: </br>");
    difference.entriesOnlyOnRight().forEach((key, value) -> SB.append(key + ": " + value + "</br>"));
    SB.append("Entries full difference : </br>");
    difference.entriesDiffering().forEach((key, value) -> SB.append(key + ": " + value + "</br>"));
    result = SB.toString();
    return result;
}
```

I wish to be able to present the difference in a more "smart" way. In other words: showing all the objects / arrays in the JONSs that don't match. What is missing or what was added to the compared JSON.

For the "categories" array my code returns a message that their is a mismatch, but doesn't state the difference in an elegant way.

What can I do?

Comment: Why Object and not a List in the Map?

Comment: I run your code looks like working, what do you mean by message mismatch. Please do following. add exactly a copy of the message you get in you console, and what is wrong with it. AND how do you expect your out will be.

Comment: The code can only show 2 differences in the months array. I want it to be displayed in a "smart" way. Telling the user the one JSON has only 3 values while the other has 6 + showing the exact difference.

Comment: The second json does have repeated values in array like Mars and Mars and in the first list Mars, so is the difference here Mars?

Comment: Mar, Apr and May - are all duplicated in the 2nd JSON.

Comment: so it is all about showing the duplicates in second json compared to the first json

Comment: Yes, but showing the difference in a smart manner.

Comment: ok thing more if mar repeated 3 times so is it duplicate should return result be Mar or Mar, Mar? becuase if it does not care about how many times it is repeated than I can give you a solution shortly

Comment: It should say Mar,Mar if Mar is duplicated 3 times.

Comment: Probably [Spring sync](https://spring.io/blog/2014/10/22/introducing-spring-sync) could rescue you

Comment: Why don't you use something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24012023/8588359
You'll have to add more code but I think that would not be an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have change a bit in your solution to get the wanted result.

I would do my difference check in List, therefore I will create method to change JSON to list of strings based on your code:

```
private static List<String> jsonToList(String json){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
    Map<String, Object> jsonMap = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    Map<String, Object> flatten = FlatMapUtil.flatten(jsonMap);
    flatten.forEach((k, v) -> list.add(v.toString()));
    return list;
}
```

---

**Update**
When I answered the question I did things a bit fast, the jsonToList was based on your code. As it is right now it is over complicated to what you are asking for. I have therefore made much lighter version using the following method in stead:

```
private static List<String> jsonToList(String json) {
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(json);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("categories");
    if (jsonArray != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

That said, now you have two choices and it is up to you to find out which one fits best to your needs and take it from here.

**End of Update**

---

for this example I have made 3 test examples

```
String main = "{\"categories\":[\"May\",\"Apr\",\"Mar\"]}";
String json1 = "{\"categories\":[\"May\",\"May\",\"Apr\",\"Apr\",\"Mar\",\"Mar\"]}";
String json2 = "{\"categories\":[\"May\",\"Apr\",\"Apr\",\"Mar\",\"Mar\",\"Mar\"]}";
String json3 = "{\"categories\":[\"May\",\"Apr\",\"Mar\",\"Mar\"]}";
```

in my second step I will create a

```
List<String> mainList = jsonToList(main);
List<String> list1 = jsonToList(json1);
```

so far so good. Now I make a method to take the extra difference of the 2 list, that mean as you requested in your comments, we take only all values that are duplicated more than once and return them in list. In this method I used hashmap only count duplicates and than take the all that is repeated more than 1 time:

```
private static List<String> diffList(List<String> mainList, List<String> secondList){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<>();
    for(String word: secondList) {
        if(mainList.contains(word)) {
            Integer count = wordCount.get(word);
            wordCount.put(word, (count == null) ? 1 : count + 1);
            if(wordCount.get(word) > 1){
                list.add(word);
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Finally I would test all cases, for instance for list1:

```
List<String> diff1 = diffList(mainList, list1);
for (String s : diff1) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

The output will be

```
May
Apr
Mar
```

for list2

```
Apr
Mar
Mar
```

And for list3

```
Mar
```

Now I will separate view method from the your method and create some thing like, just to make my code more clear and easy to work with:

```
private static String viewResult(List<String> list1, List<String> list2, List<String> duplicate){
    String result;
    StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder("</br>");
    SB.append("Entries only on LEFT: </br>");
    list1.forEach(e -> SB.append(e + "</br>"));
    SB.append("Entries only on RIGHT: </br>");
    list2.forEach(e -> SB.append(e + "</br>"));
    SB.append("Entries full difference : </br>");
    duplicate.forEach(e -> SB.append(e + "</br>"));
    result = SB.toString();
    return result;
}
```

So if we put all this code together I will be some thing like this, and the following code is to demonstrate how things works, but from here you can take it to the next level in your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String main = "{\"categories\":[\"May\",\"Apr\",\"Mar\"]}";
    String json1 = "{\"categories\":[\"May\",\"May\",\"Apr\",\"Apr\",\"Mar\",\"Mar\"]}";
    String json2 = "{\"categories\":[\"May\",\"Apr\",\"Apr\",\"Mar\",\"Mar\",\"Mar\"]}";
    String json3 = "{\"categories\":[\"May\",\"Apr\",\"Mar\",\"Mar\"]}";

    List<String> mainList = jsonToList(main);

    List<String> list1 = jsonToList(json1);
    List<String> diff1 = diffList(mainList, list1);
    for (String s : diff1) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    String view = viewResult(mainList, list1, diff1);
}

private static List<String> jsonToList(String json){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
    Map<String, Object> jsonMap = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    Map<String, Object> flatten = FlatMapUtil.flatten(jsonMap);
    flatten.forEach((k, v) -> list.add(v.toString()));
    return list;
}

private static List<String> diffList(List<String> mainList, List<String> secondList){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<>();
    for(String word: secondList) {
        if(mainList.contains(word)) {
            Integer count = wordCount.get(word);
            wordCount.put(word, (count == null) ? 1 : count + 1);
            if(wordCount.get(word) > 1){
                list.add(word);
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}

private static String viewResult(List<String> list1, List<String> list2, List<String> duplicate){
    String result;
    StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder("</br>");
    SB.append("Entries only on LEFT: </br>");
    list1.forEach(e -> SB.append(e + "</br>"));
    SB.append("Entries only on RIGHT: </br>");
    list2.forEach(e -> SB.append(e + "</br>"));
    SB.append("Entries full difference : </br>");
    duplicate.forEach(e -> SB.append(e + "</br>"));
    result = SB.toString();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want something more generic with a good diff you could utilize AssertJ here.
Its usually used for Testing, but the diff looks really good and you can also use it in normal code.

Example:

```
Expecting:
  <["Mai", "Apr", "Mar"]>
to contain exactly in any order:
  <["May", "Apr", "Mar", "Mar"]>
elements not found:
  <["May", "Mar"]>
and elements not expected:
  <["Mai"]>
```

Can be created by:

```
[...]
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;

public class JsonTest {
    final static String arr = " [\n"+
            "            \"Mai\",\n"+
            "            \"Apr\",\n"+
            "            \"Mar\"\n"+
            "          ]";
    final static String arr2 = " [\n"+
            "            \"May\",\n"+
            "            \"Apr\",\n"+
            "            \"Mar\",\n"+
            "            \"Mar\"\n"+
            "          ]";

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(smartJSONsCompare(arr,arr2));
    }

    private static String smartJSONsCompare(String leftJson, String rightJson) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();
        List<String> left = gson.fromJson(leftJson, type);
        List<String> right = gson.fromJson(rightJson, type);
        try{
            Assertions.assertThat(left).containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf(right);
        }catch(AssertionError  ae){
            return ae.getMessage();
        }
        return "Matched";
    }
  }
```

I added the dependencies in gradle with:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.1")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a patch between your two JSON Objects have a look at [json-patch](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-patch).

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.github.fge.jsonpatch.diff.JsonDiff;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonPatchTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String jsonFirst = "{\"categories\":[\"May\",\"Apr\",\"Mar\"]}";
        String jsonSecond = "{\"categories\":[\"May\",\"May\",\"Apr\",\"Apr\",\"Mar\",\"Mar\"]}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNodeFirst = mapper.readTree(jsonFirst);
        JsonNode jsonNodeSecond = mapper.readTree(jsonSecond);

        JsonNode patchNode = JsonDiff.asJson(jsonNodeFirst, jsonNodeSecond);

        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(patchNode));
    }
}
```

Would produce the following output for your scenario:

```
[ {
  "op" : "replace",
  "path" : "/categories/1",
  "value" : "May"
}, {
  "op" : "replace",
  "path" : "/categories/2",
  "value" : "Apr"
}, {
  "op" : "add",
  "path" : "/categories/-",
  "value" : "Apr"
}, {
  "op" : "add",
  "path" : "/categories/-",
  "value" : "Mar"
}, {
  "op" : "add",
  "path" : "/categories/-",
  "value" : "Mar"
} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should handle json arrays on your own in order to present their difference in a more "smart" way. [Here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html) is a library which contains `CollectionUtils` class with `disjunction` method.

```
MapDifference<String, Object> difference = Maps.difference(leftMap, rightMap);
difference.entriesDiffering().forEach((key, value) -> {
  Object left = value.leftValue();
  Object right = value.rightValue();
  if (left instanceof Iterable && right instanceof Iterable) {
    Collection<?> diff = CollectionUtils.disjunction((Iterable<?>) right, (Iterable<?>) left);
    System.out.println(key + " -> " + diff);
  }
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me (2 years ago) on production.

```
public class App {
private final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().create();

public boolean isDifference(final String path, Map<String, Object> oldData, Map<String, Object> newData) {
    MapDifference<String, Object> difference = Maps.difference(oldData, newData);
    difference.entriesOnlyOnLeft().forEach((key, value) -> {
        publishChange(Action.REMOVE, path, key, value);
    });
    difference.entriesOnlyOnRight().forEach((key, value) -> {
        publishChange(Action.ADD, path, key, value);
    });
    difference.entriesDiffering().forEach((key, value) -> {
        if (value.rightValue() instanceof Map && value.leftValue() instanceof Map) {
            if (!path.isEmpty()) {
                key = path.concat("-").concat(key);
            }
            isDifference(key, (Map) value.leftValue(), (Map) value.rightValue());
        } else {
            publishChange(Action.MODIFY, path, key, value);
        }
    });
    return !difference.areEqual();
}

public void publishChange(Action action, String path, String key, Object value) {
    if (value instanceof MapDifference.ValueDifference) {
        value = ((MapDifference.ValueDifference) value).rightValue();
    }
    JsonElement jsonValue = GSON.toJsonTree(value);
    String event = createEvent(action, path, key, jsonValue);
    System.out.println("Differrence: " + event);
}

public String createEvent(Action action, String paths, String key, JsonElement value) {
    JsonObject root = new JsonObject();
    JsonArray arrPaths = new JsonArray();
    for (String path : paths.split("-")) {
        arrPaths.add(path);
    }
    root.addProperty("action", action.toString());
    root.add("paths", arrPaths);
    JsonObject data = new JsonObject();
    data.addProperty("key", key);
    data.add("value", value);
    root.add("data", data);
    return root.toString();
}

public static enum Action {
    ADD, REMOVE, MODIFY
}}
```

Test/ Example:

```
public class AppTest {
@Test
public void testAppHasAGreeting() {
    App classUnderTest = new App();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setPrettyPrinting()
            .create();
    // JsonOld: {"a":1,"b":1,"c":true,"array":[1,2,3],"object":{"arrayKey":["a","b","c","d"]}}
    String jsonOld = "{\"a\":1,\"b\":1,\"c\":true,\"array\":[1,2,3],\"object\":{\"arrayKey\":[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\",\"d\"]}}";
    // JsonNew: {"a":2,"b":1,"array":[1,2,3,2],"another":{"d":false,"e":["a","b","c"]},"object":{"booleanKey":true,"arrayKey":["a","b","c"]}}
    String jsonNew = "{\"a\":2,\"b\":1,\"array\":[1,2,3,2],\"another\":{\"d\":false,\"e\":[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]},\"object\":{\"booleanKey\":true,\"arrayKey\":[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]}}";

    Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {
    }.getType();
    Map<String, Object> jsonOldAsMap = gson.fromJson(jsonOld, mapType);
    Map<String, Object> jsonNewAsMap = gson.fromJson(jsonNew, mapType);
    System.out.println("Old Json: " + gson.toJson(jsonOldAsMap));
    System.out.println("New Json: " + gson.toJson(jsonNewAsMap));
    System.out.println("========== Result ==========");
    // When
    boolean diff = classUnderTest.isDifference("", jsonOldAsMap, jsonNewAsMap);
    // Then
    assertTrue(diff);
}}
```

The result will print like this:

Differrence: {"action":"REMOVE","paths":[""],"data":{"key":"c","value":true}}

Differrence: {"action":"ADD","paths":[""],"data":{"key":"another","value":{"d":false,"e":["a","b","c"]}}}

Differrence: {"action":"MODIFY","paths":[""],"data":{"key":"a","value":2.0}}

Differrence: {"action":"MODIFY","paths":[""],"data":{"key":"array","value":[1.0,2.0,3.0,2.0]}}

Differrence: {"action":"ADD","paths":["object"],"data":{"key":"booleanKey","value":true}}

Differrence: {"action":"MODIFY","paths":["object"],"data":{"key":"arrayKey","value":["a","b","c"]}}

The code available here: https://github.com/liemle3893/compare-json