# How to send a map in socket.emit in nodejs server and how can we retrive it in android(Java)?

Tags: android, socket.io

"How can I retrieve the "users" map value in android from socket.emit('allusers') ?  What to do in my client-side in android (java) to retrieve the users."

```
var users = {}; //Map design

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

console.log('user connected')

socket.on('join', function(userNickname) {

        console.log(userNickname +" : has joined the chat "  );

         users[socket.id] = userNickname;`enter code here`

     socket.emit('allusers', {
        users: users
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `socket.io` library:

1. Add dependency in your `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
  // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
  exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

2.Connect the socket:

```
String url = <YOUR_HOST>;
Socket socket = IO.socket(url, options);
```

3. Request API and parse data (**UPDATE**):

```java
socket.emit("allusers", "{}", new Ack() {
  @Override
  public void call(Object... args) {
    // add validation (check args length; their format, etc)
    JSONObject users = (JSONObject) args[0];  // or JSONArray, or primitive - what your server returns
    // do business with users

    try {
      Map<String, String> parsedUsers = new HashMap<>();
      Iterator<String> keys = users.keys();
      while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String k = keys.next();
        String us = users.getString(k);
        parsedUsers.put(k, us);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // handle error
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: when I used '  users.toString() ' it returns : {"x2Qdscs12c":"x2Qdscs12c","a1eacx21":"a1eacx21"} . How can I put user into a hashmap?

Comment: @heroxxx If the server response is map "String"->"String", you can use snippet, shown in the updated answer. For more complex cases, please, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720759 and its answers

Comment: @heroxxx, you are welcome. If the suggested approach solved the problem, please, mark the answer as correct