# How to map JSON to Java HashMap

Tags: java, json, dictionary, jackson-databind

I have a JSON like this: `[{key:key1, value:value1}, {key:key2, value:value2}, ..., {key:keyn, value:valuen}]`

and I need a HashMap in Java from that json like: `{key1:value1, key2:value2, ..., keyn:valuen}`

Is there a simple way to have it converted like this? I'm trying with Jackson but don't know how to specify key and value keywords.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720759/convert-a-json-string-to-a-hashmap check this

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24012023/7137584

I would recommend using Jackson library:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<>() {};
Map<String, Object> mapping = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonStr, typeRef);
```

Comment: This code fails for the given input with this exception: ``Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.HashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>` out of START_ARRAY token``

Answer (score 0):

The input JSON describes an array/list of map entries where each entry is a POJO:

```java
@Data
class Entry {
    private String key;
    private String value; // the type of value may be Object
}
```

Here `@Data` is a Lombok annotation which provides getters, setters, `toString`, etc.

So, at first a list of map entries is read, which is converted then to the map:

```java
String json = "[{\"key\":\"key1\", \"value\":\"value1\"}, {\"key\":\"key2\", \"value\":\"value2\"}, {\"key\":\"keyN\", \"value\":\"valueN\"}]";

// step 1: read raw list of entries
List<Entry> input = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Entry>>() {});

// step 2: convert to map
Map<String, String> mapRead = input.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));

System.out.println(mapRead);
```

Output:

```
{key1=value1, key2=value2, keyN=valueN}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using the [JSON-P](https://javadoc.io/doc/javax.json/javax.json-api/latest/overview-summary.html) api.

```
import javax.json.*;

var str = "[{\"key\":\"key1\", \"value\":\"value1\"}, {\"key\":\"key2\", \"value\":\"value2\"}, {\"key\":\"keyN\", \"value\":\"valueN\"}]";
JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(str));
JsonArray jarr = reader.readArray();
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
for(JsonValue jv : jarr) {
    JsonObject jo = (JsonObject)jv;
    map.put(jo.getString("key"), jo.getString("value") );
}
System.out.println(map);
```

I am using a `JsonReader` to convert the `String` to a `JsonArray` object.
Each entry of this `JsonArray` is a `JsonObject` like `{key: keyX, value: valueX}`.
I get the values corresponding to 'key' and 'value' and add them to a `HashMap` using a for loop.