# How to Extract the currencies json result string

Tags: java, json

In my java project i got the currency code and its expansion as a json string as a result of an api call.Below is the json result.

```
      String jsonString = {
    "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
    "AFN": "Afghan Afghani",
    "ALL": "Albanian Lek",
    "AMD": "Armenian Dram",
    "ANG": "Netherlands Antillean Guilder",
    "AOA": "Angolan Kwanza",
    "ARS": "Argentine Peso",
    "AUD": "Australian Dollar",
    "AWG": "Aruban Florin",
    "AZN": "Azerbaijani Manat",
    "BAM": "Bosnia-Herzegovina Convertible Mark",
    "BBD": "Barbadian Dollar",
    "BDT": "Bangladeshi Taka",
    "BGN": "Bulgarian Lev",
    "BHD": "Bahraini Dinar",
    "BIF": "Burundian Franc",
    "BMD": "Bermudan Dollar",
    "BND": "Brunei Dollar",
    "BOB": "Bolivian Boliviano",
    "BRL": "Brazilian Real",
    "BSD": "Bahamian Dollar",
    "BTC": "Bitcoin",
    "BTN": "Bhutanese Ngultrum",
    ......
    }
```

Now how can i extract the key value pair from above json string where the currency code comes as the key and expansion comes as the value, so that i can store it to a list or map.

Comment: Wait! In Java we have class Currency which represents a currency. Currencies are identified by their ISO 4217 currency codes. Give me a reason for not using it before going further.

Comment: See this Stackoverflow response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java.

Comment: More relevant duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/convert-json-to-map

Comment: @cricket_007 I think the structure of my json is different from that

Comment: @boky I think the structure of my json is different from that

Comment: Did you even try it? JSON is key value pairs. Doesn't matter what format you have

Comment: @cricket_007 which library i should import for ObjectMapper() ? fasterxml or codehaus ?

Comment: One was renamed to the other. I cannot remember which

Comment: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind` is the latest version. If you see both, then you are using mixed versions of the library

Comment: @cricket_007 Is there any other way to loop this key value pair, when we iterate this hash map it will not give the correct order.Its not necessary to put the key-value pair to a hashmap

Comment: TreeMap should be ordered

Comment: @cricket_007 but how can i map this json String to treemap

Comment: I don't really know what you're wanting to get. Sorry. There's like 5 json libraries that I know. You seem to have picked Jackson, so like, you need to iterate the JSON tree http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760138/parsing-json-in-java-without-knowing-json-format

Comment: @cricket_007 I just want to map the json string in its alphabetical order as in the question.If i map them to hashmap, then when i iterate that map i getting the re result in unordered manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jackson`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for reading json from `Inputstream/String/byte[]/Url/File/Reader` to `Map<String,String>` using below code:

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();// do this construction at application level. Not for every call.
  Map<String,String> codeDescMap = mapper.readValue(source,mapper.getTypeFactory()
        .constructMapLikeType(Map.class,
              String.class,String.class));
```

where source can be `Inputstream/String/byte[]/Url/File/Reader` with valid json structure.

Comment: This doesn't answer how to get any data from the JSON. And Jackson seems like it is unnecessary

Comment: Use case of op is to read data from api call and store it in map or list.Since it is api call he will any how needs to deserialize data.