# how to parse json with variable keys at the root of json retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit2

How to parse json with variable keys the root of json using retrofit.

In the retrofit class that maps the response i defined a 
`Map<String, DateObject>` but didn't use `@SerializedName` since i don't know the key.

This is the json im trying to parse:

```
{
    "2017-04-01": [{...}, {...}, {...}],
    "2017-04-02": [{...}],
    "2017-04-03": []
}
```

Comment: i think you should manually do it.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760138/parsing-json-in-java-without-knowing-json-format

Comment: I don't think you need the SerializedName annotation. Have you loojed at the object Retrofit gives back, Map<String, DateObject> should work fine

Comment: Retrofit requires a well-defined schema (if using Gson). You don't have one here, so you must parse manually

Comment: it gives back nulll with Map<String, DateObject> and no annotation

Comment: @Ascorbin can you show me an example?

Comment: You can use parse it to

    Map<String, List<ObjectType>>

Comment: // response
`{
 "2017-04-11": [
  {
   "price": 1132.0,
  }
}`

// class
`class Response {

    private Map<String, DateObject> map;

    public Map<String, DateObject> getMap() {
        return map;
    }
    public setDays(Map<String, DateObject> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}`

using this class and getting this response returns a null, think i will have to do it manual as suggested

Comment: i used `Map<String, ArrayList<ObjectData>>` and still returned null

Comment: @nysertxs Aren't you just confused with `retrofit2.Response<T>`? If your JSON is just a top-level map, you have just declare your service interface method return type like `Call<Map<String, List<Whatever>>>` -- this would be fine then (so your `service.getXXX()` returns a `Call` that returns a `retrofit2.Response<T>` via `execute`). It works for me without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i solved it with this method in the retrofit interface:

`Observable<Map<String, List<Value>>> getMap();`

and no need to create a manual parser