# Parsing JSON in Java without knowing JSON format in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Is there an equivalent in Javascript for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19760249/8090459) following functionality achieved through Java?

To be able to iterate through an simple to complex/ nested JSON structure without knowing the JSON format.

I am in need of this functionality to get hold of all the innermost keys and that hold a direct value and not object/array as its value.

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lap4u0h/), Object.keys() only gives the outermost keys. I want to be able to get (id,  type)

```
console.log(Object.keys(x));
```

Comment: you can loop over a object properties without the use of keys

Comment: I have seen this answered on this site multiple times. Go look

Comment: Make use of `Object.keys()`

Comment: You can use `JSON.parse` then use `Object.keys()`

Comment: @GabrielCarneiro: Object.keys() gives only the outermost keys

Comment: Then start looping them

Comment: build a recursive function that analyzes the whole array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1):

You can build it yourself, just iterate the keys of the object recursively if it is an object, see this small example:

```
    const getAllPropertiesRecursively = (obj) => {
    const propertyKeys = [];
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        const value = obj[key];
        if (value && !Array.isArray(value)) {
            if (value.toString() === '[object Object]') {
                propertyKeys.push(...getAllPropertiesRecursively(value));
            } else {
                propertyKeys.push({[key]: value}); // here you store the keys and values that are not array nor object
            }
        }
    });
    return propertyKeys;
}
```

So when you call this method like this:

`getAllPropertiesRecursively({a:1, b:2, c: { d: 1}, e: [1,2,3,4], f: {g:2}});`

You get an array like:

`[{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {d: 1}, {g: 2}]`

You can edit the line with the comment to store the data in the way you want

Comment: Consider this data : key array is empty : {
"i": {
"i1": [{
"id": "0001",
"b": {
"b1": [{
"d1": "t1",
"coordinates": [19.291422,73.53197 ]
},
{
"d3": "t3",
"d4": "t4"
}
]
},
"c": [{
"d5": "t5",
"r1": ["1", "2", "3"]
},
{
"d6": "t6"
}
]
},
{
"id": "0002",
"b": {
"b1": [{
"d1": "t1",
"d2": "t2"
},
{
"d3": "t3",
"d4": "t4"
}
]
},
"c": [{
"d5": "t5"
},
{
"d6": "t6"
}
]

}

]
}
}

Comment: be careful with (typeof obj[property] == "object") because:
typeof [] === 'object' // true
typeof null === 'object' // true
typeof new Date() === 'object' // true

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

In any case, I just gave you a snippet of what you could do, you can adapt it to your own needs.