# How to check if a Json element isJsonPrimitive

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I am changing some code from Gson to Jackson where I have to check if the type of the current element is a primitive.

I could do something like this with Gson:

```
JsonElement element = entry.getValue();
if (element.isJsonPrimitive()) {
    ...
}
```

in Jackson, the Json node type is one of

`JsonNodeType: { ARRAY, BINARY, BOOLEAN, MISSING, NULL, NUMBER, OBJECT, POJO, STRING }`

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760138/parsing-json-in-java-without-knowing-json-format) helps

Comment: You could try `JsonNode.isValueNode()` which will return `true` for anything other than ARRAY, OBJECT and MISSING.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Jackson`'s `JsonNode` class has `isValueNode` method should do the same:

```
@Override
public final boolean isValueNode()
{
    switch (getNodeType()) {
        case ARRAY: case OBJECT: case MISSING:
            return false;
        default:
            return true;
    }
}
```

If node is: `ARRAY`, `OBJECT` or `MISSING` it returns `false`; for other types - `true`